# Next.js 13 dynamic routes based on external JSON

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In Next.js 13 when creating a route i.e. "/projects/project-one" you would create a file tree like below...

`app / projects / [project-id] / page.tsx`

The problem here is that this folder structure has to be created manually by a developer and then changes need to be deployed

I'm trying to create a dynamic folder tree based on an external CMS

consider a CMS where the pages are created dynamically and a JSON payload like below is created

```
{
    routes: [
        {
            "slug": "index",
            "folder": "root",
            "actual_url": "/"
        },
        {
            "slug": "project-one",
            "folder": "projects",
            "actual_url": "/projects/project-one"
        },
        {
            "slug": "project-two",
            "folder": "projects",
            "actual_url": "/projects/project-two"
        },
        {
            "slug": "about-us",
            "folder": "index",
            "actual_url": "/about-us"
        },
        {
            "slug": "programme-alpha",
            "folder": "programs",
            "actual_url": "/programs/programme-alpha"
        },
        {
            "slug": "red",
            "folder": "colors/dark",
            "actual_url": "/colors/dark/red"
        },
    ]
}
```

ideally over time the CMS user would update the routes (or pages) via the CMS and this would also update the Next.js folder structure without a developer and manual deployment

My question is, is something like this possible and if so how would you go about achieving something like this? and what would the folder structure look like?